# Replace attribute value in a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

I have an array in this format:

```
var arr = [{id: 1, age: 25, money: 2500},{id: 10, age: 10, money: 100},{id: 115, age: 80, money: 1350}]
```

What I want is to replace every id value with null. My first idea would have been to build a regex im combination with a for loop. But is there maybe a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What would you want to use a regular expression _on_ here, when your data is not even in string form to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```js
const source = [{id: 1, age: 25, money: 2500},{id: 10, age: 10, money: 100},{id: 115, age: 80, money: 1350}];

const destination = source.map((el) => ({ ...el, id: null }));

// For demo purpose
console.log(destination);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [{id: 1, age: 25, money: 2500},{id: 10, age: 10, money: 100},{id: 115, age: 80, money: 1350}] 

arr.forEach(item => {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
    if(key ==='id') {
      item[key] = null;
    }

  });
})


console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Just a little comment to improve your code, you should name your varianble to represent the type of data. More specificly you should rename the `array` variable with `item` for example (or `user` if we know for sure those are users ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Read through [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) :

> The RegExp object is used for matching text with a pattern.

Here, working with regex would be really unefficient since you work with objects

---

There are multiple ways of doing what you want :

You can use a `for i` loop to loop through your items

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, age: 25, money: 2500},{id: 10, age: 10, money: 100},{id: 115, age: 80, money: 1350}]

for (let i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
  arr[i].id = null
}

console.log(arr)
```

Or with the [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method on arrays :

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, age: 25, money: 2500},{id: 10, age: 10, money: 100},{id: 115, age: 80, money: 1350}]

arr.forEach(item => {
  item.id = null
}) 

console.log(arr)
```

---

You could also have used [Array#Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, age: 25, money: 2500},{id: 10, age: 10, money: 100},{id: 115, age: 80, money: 1350}]

const arrWithoutIds = arr.map(item => {
  item.id = null
  return item
})

console.log(arrWithoutIds)
```